# Better referencing syntax for nested objects?

Tags: javascript, object

I could not find anything online, but I'm curious if there's a more concise syntax for the following example:

```
if ( obj[a][b][c] != 0 ) {
    obj[a][b][c] = ( obj[a][b][c] / 2 ) + obj[a][b][c] + 100;
    obj[x][y][z] = obj[a][b][c];
}
```

I know for the times that I'm working with the actual value I could just cache it in a temporary variable, but I'm more interested in replacing the "obj[...] = " part with something more concise.

Comment: obj[a][b][c]=obj[x][y][z]=(a=>a?a/2+a+100:a)(obj[a][b][c]);

Answer (score 3):

Well you could extract a variable and as [@Jonas W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-w) noted in the comments you can combine assigments:

```
var cellP = obj[a][b];
var cell = cellP[c];
if ( cell != 0 ) {
    obj[x][y][z] = cellP[c] = 1.5 * cell + 100;
}
```